# Google Maps iframe in Ionic with Dynamic Coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, ionic-framework

I want to show Google maps pin with dynamic Coordinates like whenever user update his coordinates map will be updated
here is my code

```
for eg dynamic coordinates {{artist_latitude}} {{artist_longitude}}
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.7127837,-74.0059413&amp;key=abcxyz" width="600" height="450"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why not use the [Google Maps plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add url in your ts file and then bind it to your iframe tag like this.

In your .html file:`<iframe  height="50%" width="100%" [src]="url" name="iframe_a"></iframe>`

In your .ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer){
let address = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.7127837,-74.0059413&amp;key=abcxyz"
url = this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(address);
}
```

Comment: and where I add my dynamic coordinates which coming from db
in java script when want to pass veriables in url we add
http://url.com/?dat1=+var1

Comment: "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q="+latitude+","+longitude+"&amp;key=abcxyz";